# Visual Studio does not creates a proxy for OData v3 service

Tags: visual-studio, odata

I have created an OData v3 service which includes EntityTypes with properties whose type is a collection (http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/common-schema-definition-language-csdl#csdl5.1), for example:

```
<EntityType Name="Apps">
…
<Property Name="tags" Nullable="false" Type="Collection(Edm.String)"/>
…
</EntityType>
```

I have created a client for that service with Visual Studio (2012 and 2013) through right click in the project > Add Service Reference which creates a proxy class (AndroidContext in my example) for the service.

My problem is, when I try to retrieve an entity:

```
var app = androidContext.Apps.Where(a => a.Title == "Some title").First();
```

it throws an InvalidOperationException:

"Collection types are only supported in version 3.0 of the OData protocol and higher versions. They are not supported in version 2.0."

I have found that the proxy class created by Visual Studio has only one constructor which receives as only parameter the URI of the service. This constructor calls a base constructor (of the inherited class DataServiceContext) that use Odata v2 by default:

```
public DataServiceContext(Uri serviceRoot)
  : this(serviceRoot, DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2)
{
}
```

I don’t understand why there is not a constructor that allows the creation of a proxy for OData v3. The solution I have used is to declare a new constructor for the proxy class (is partial) that allows OData v3:

```
public partial class AndroidContext
{
    public AndroidContext(Uri serviceRoot, DataServiceProtocolVersion version) :
        base(serviceRoot, version)
    {
        //The same that the generated constructor do
    }
}
```

Does someone knows why Visual Studio does not allows the use of OData v3 by default? Does someone knows another solution?

Comment: I've also created a service reference of a V3 service but my constructor has DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3. Would you like to check if the value of the m:DataServiceVersion attribute of the edmx:DataServices attribute of the metadata of your service is 3.0?

Comment: Here is a fragment of the metadata document of my v3 service. The m:DataServiceVersion is 3.0: `<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" Version="1.0"> <edmx:DataServices xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" m:DataServiceVersion="3.0">`